# How can I fix this error when executing GAE SDK in Ubuntu?

Tags: google-app-engine, ubuntu, python-2.7, arduino

I was following the outlines of this guide (http://www.instructables.com/id/Aquaponics-Online-Temperature-and-Humidity/step3/Testing-GAE-SDK/), so I can try to innovate the design for my own aquaponic system.
However, when I typed "$ python2.7 AppEngine/dev_appserver.py IAquaponics_DHT/myapsystem" into my terminal, I received an error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfn2d.jpg (my stacktrace is below).

note: "*_*_" is to blank out my name.

```
____@____-Linux:~$ python2.7 AppEngine/dev_appserver.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "AppEngine/dev_appserver.py", line 182, in <module>
    _run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "AppEngine/dev_appserver.py", line 178, in _run_file
    execfile(script_path, globals_)
  File "/home/____/AppEngine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 32, in <module>
    from google.appengine.tools.devappserver2.admin import admin_server
  File "/home/____/AppEngine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/admin/admin_server.py", line 25, in <module>
    import webapp2
  File "/home/____/AppEngine/lib/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 25, in <module>
    import webob
  File "/home/____/AppEngine/lib/webob-1.2.3/webob/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from webob.response import *
  File "/home/____/AppEngine/lib/webob-1.2.3/webob/response.py", line 9, in <module>
    import zlib
ImportError: No module named zlib
```

Comment: How come Someone voted me down?

Comment: It was not me. 
But I would guess that someone looking for google-app-engine questions saw your question, and was irritated.

Comment: My guess is your stacktrace is an image somewhere, not code in the question.  Also did you try and read the stacktrace and understand what it is telling you.  One could easily think you got a stacktrace and asked SO without tryjng to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: The actual code in question is contains 182 lines and is publicly available here: http://googleappengine.googlecode.com/files/google_appengine_1.8.0.zip. I have tried to fix my problem, but the only solutions I have found is that I am missing a package. Yet, the sudo commands either give me an error or do not help me.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried (run enter this in the terminal window to install the install a package for zlib)

```
    sudo apt-get install zlib
```

start there

Comment: The terminal replies back that it is "unable to locate package zlib."

Comment: try $sudo apt-get install zlibc

Comment: Really, lets see if zlib is still your issue. Enter python interactively **$python**
then try to use zlib  **>>>import zlib** 
Do you get an error?

Comment: Do you have anymore solutions?

Comment: (The issue is some code can not import the zlib Modules, But you are able to import the Module in your own code)   I have no more solutions, but I advice you to re-post.People will be watching the new questions as they are posted. Python is very popular, someone out there will know more then me.